# Is it possible to feed scalar value on tensorflow mobile android?

Tags: tensorflow

Android Tensorflow Mobile Java Inference API does not support feeding scalar values to graph.
So if I try to feed my scalar value as following I get error for bad shape.

```
    boolean[] phaseTrain = {false};
    inferenceInterface.feed("phase_train:0", phaseTrain, 1);
    --->
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [1]
```

So I'd like to know if there is any way to feed scalar values to the graph on Android Tensorflow Mobile.
Or should I modify the graph not to use scalar values?

Actually I'm trying to make an Android application that uses facenet model at
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5MzpY9kBtDVZ2RpVDYwWmxoSUk/edit

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by add following code in

```
~/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java

+  public void feed(String inputName, boolean src) {
+                 this.addFeed(inputName, Tensor.create(Boolean.valueOf(src), Boolean.class));
+  }
```

Thanks for reviewing!

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, but  probably it is not working for TF >= 1.5, since they use java package, so changing this file doesn't have an effect.

Comment: Did you find a better way to feed scalars?

Answer (score 0):

With Tensorflow 1.12, you can do it this way:

```
boolean[] phaseTrain = {false};
long[] phaseTrainShape = {};
inferenceInterface.feed("phase_train:0", phaseTrain, phaseTrainShape);
```

Answer (score -1):

please remove 1 like this:

```
inferenceInterface.feed("phase_train:0", phaseTrain);
```

Then the problem could be fixed.